# Cypher - Order By and Distinct Clash

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have to return three properties from the result. But the results should be ordered. So in order to order the results, the add that property to the return statement.
Query:

```
RETURN n.prop1,n.prop2,n.prop3
```

Ex:

```
prop1   prop2   prop3   
a        3       2   
b        4       3   
b        4       3
```

This result is not ordered, so I ordered using another property
Query:

```
RETURN n.prop1,n.prop2,n.prop3 ORDER BY n.prop4
```

Ex:

```
prop1   prop2   prop3  prop4  
b        4       3      0.8
b        4       3      0.6
a        3       2      0.4
```

Now, irrespective of the prop4 value. I have to Return distinct value like
Ex:

```
prop1   prop2   prop3  prop4  
b        4       3      0.8
a        3       2      0.4
```

But since the prop4 is distinct for two rows, I am unable to make distinct prop1 values in the return statement. And thus ORDER BY and DISTINCT got clashed.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 rows for `b`, with distict prop4 value, so how do you want to order it? You need to decide which `prop4` you want to use for ordering.

You could for example use the aggregation and take the max (that seems to be what you did in your last step):

```
UNWIND [{prop1:'a',prop2:3,prop3:2,prop4:0.4}, {prop1:'b',prop2:4,prop3:3,prop4:0.8},{prop1:'b',prop2:4,prop3:3,prop4:0.6}] as n
RETURN DISTINCT n.prop1,n.prop2,n.prop3,max(n.prop4) as maxProp4 
ORDER BY maxProp4 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want (assuming your nodes have the `Foo` label):

```
MATCH (n:Foo)
WITH n ORDER BY n.prop4
RETURN n.prop1, n.prop2, n.prop3, COLLECT(n.prop4) AS p4;
```

It first sorts all the `Foo` nodes by `prop4`, and then returns an ordered collection of `prop4` values for each distinct combination of `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3` values.

Here is a sample result:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| n.prop1 | n.prop2 | n.prop3 | p4        |
+-----------------------------------------+
| "b"     | 4       | 3       | [0.6,0.8] |
| "a"     | 3       | 2       | [0.4]     |
+-----------------------------------------+
```